# how can I view/extract pixels from an image based on mask image

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to achieve this: view/extract pixels in source image by using a mask image.

[image]

The simple case might be using "any" pixel in mask. But it would be better to define which color pixel should be used for masking ("advanced case" in image above)

I tried `convert source.png mask.png -compose Screen -composite source-filtered.png` but the pixels from source are modified..

Here are links to actual files:

[image: Source image]

[image: Mask image]

[image: Expected result]

Edit: added links for actual files

Comment: Please post separate images for us to test. It is hard to cut-out the exact same areas of each of your source and mask images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a practical way to apply this mask to many images?

Yes, in Imagemagick, you can use mogrify to process all images in a folder. I assume that you are using the same mask image for all images in the folder and that all images are the same size.

First create a directory (or use what you have) for all the images you want to change. Lets say it is on the desktop in folder test1. Create a new empty directory. Lets say on the desktop as folder test2. Then create a binary mask image from your colored mask on the desktop. You cannot have a png mask in the folder of pngs that you want to change. If you make the mask a gif, then it can be in the folder, since mogrify will only process pngs as I have specified it below.

```
convert mask.png -fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque red -fill black +opaque white newmask.png
```

[image]

Then use mogrify to process all the files in test1 and put the output in test2.

```
cd
cd desktop/test1
mogrify -format png -path ../test2 -draw 'image multiply 0,0 0,0 "../newmask.png"' *.png
```

See
https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify
https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose

Comment: If this was helpful, please consider giving it an up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [`-fx`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) operation would work best.

```
convert Source.png Mask.png -fx 'v == #E8212D ? u : v' output.png
```

[image: output.png]

Or

```
convert Source.png Mask.png -fx 'v == #E8212D ? u : #E6E6E6' output.png
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: thanks for the pointer for `-fx` operator..In my case the following works perfect: 

`convert source.png mask.png -fx 'v.r == 1 ? u : 0' output.png`

interestingly, it *does not work* when I use pixel color, just like you suggested;

`convert source.png mask.png -fx 'v == #FF0000 ? u : 0' output.png`

Answer (score 1):

Given your new separate images, this is one way to do what you want in Imagemagick.

Source:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Convert the mask into a binary image, with white where it is red and black everywhere else. Then do a compose multiply -composite to combine them.

```
convert source.png \
\( mask.png -fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque red \
   -fill black +opaque white \) \
-compose multiply -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thanks for the answer. it looks quite complicated but as long as it works, doesn't matter.. I'll try the code and give feedback soon.. This might be a different question but, is there a practical way to apply this mask to many images? I can write a loop in shell but I was wondering if there's Imagemagick way to apply one mask to many images?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provided the images separately. I have cropped them out, but they do not match perfectly. Nevertheless, you can see how it would work using Imagemagick.

The first this is to produce an gray and white only background image from your mask image. Make both the red and blue squares into the same gray color as the other squares.

Mask Image:

[image]

```
convert mask.png -fuzz 60% \
-fill "gray(230)" -opaque "rgb(237,28,36)" \
-fill "gray(230)" -opaque "rgb(0,102,179)" \
background.png
```

[image]

Now take the background, your source image and process the mask so that red becomes white and everything else becomes black. Then composite the source over the background using the binary mask image.

```
convert background.png source.png \
\( mask.png -fuzz 1% -fill black +opaque "rgb(237,28,36)" \
    -fill white +opaque black \) \
-compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: terribly sorry for that :( I added links to actual files.. The original image was for illustration purposes, so that I can explain the problem.. Sorry for making you go through cropping process..